# How to call option.value in the loop of product.variants in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have one hidden dropdown and two `variant-selector` dropdowns.
 One dropdown is for `color` and the second one is for `size`.
 I want to add `size` data in `data-size=""` and `color` data in `data-color=""` in the dropdown of `name=id`.

```html
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">          
 {% if product.variants.size > 1 %} 
 {% for option in product.options_with_values %}          
    <select  class="variant-selector {{option.name}}" data-var="{{forloop.index}}">
       {% if product.available %}
       {% for values in option.values %}
          <option value="{{values}}">{{values}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
    </select>
 {% endfor %}
          
 <select name="id" style="display:none;" id="data{{forloop.index}}">
 {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}
       <option data-size="" data-color="" value="{{ variant.id }}"  >{{ variant.title }}</option>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
 {% if variant.available%}
    <input type="hidden" min="1" type="number" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}"  class="btn add-to-cart" />
 {% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}"  class="btn add-to-cart" disabled="disabled">
 {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you just looking at the `data-size="" data-color=""` part? If so, I think that `{{ variant.option1 }}`/`{{ variant.option2 }}` should get you what you're after...

Comment: If you want to be more generic, you could do something like `{% for option in product.options %} data-{{ option | handle }}="{{ variant.options[forloop.index0] }}" {% endfor %}` to make your data-entries so that a product with different options or the options in a different order still work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As [Dave B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592369/dave-b) comment I don't need `option.value` in the loop of `product.variants` in Shopify. I simply add `data-size="{{ variant.option1 }}"` and `data-color="{{ variant.option2 }}"`

```html
<select name="id" style="display:none;" id="data{{forloop.index}}">             
 {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}             
       <option data-size="{{ variant.option1 }}" data-color="{{ variant.option2 }}" value="{{ variant.id }}"  >{{ variant.title }}</option>             
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}             
</select>
```